# Syntax for Function Return Type in a Header File for a Nested Template Class Return Type in C++

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, inner-classes

I am working on building my own vector class similar to the vector you would find the C++ STL. In my header file have two classes, my vector class and my iterator class, which is a nested template class. I am wondering what is the proper syntax is for the return type for a nested iterator class. In this case with my code, I am looking for the right way to write the proper return type syntax for my `begin()` function and my `end()` function, both of which are in my vector class. Both `begin()` and `end()` are supposed to have return type of `vector <T> :: iterator` but that does not seem to be working. Here is how my code is currently set up.

```
template <class T>
iterator;

/************************************************
 * VECTOR
 * A class that holds stuff
 ***********************************************/
template <class T>
class vector
{
public:
   // code removed for brevity

   // Methods of the Vector class
   vector <T> :: iterator begin();
   vector <T> :: iterator end();


private:
   // Code removed for brevity
};

/**************************************************
* VECTOR ITERATOR
* An iterator through array
*************************************************/
template <class T>
class vector <T> :: iterator
{
    // ...code removed for brevity
};
```

Further, do I have the right code for the following two lines which are at the top of my .h file?

```
template <class T>
iterator;
```

Or would it be this?

```
template <class T>
vector <T> :: iterator;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it's `vector::iterator`, Get rid of the forward declaration and define it inside `vector`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types

Comment: @user4581301 I am not sure what you mean when you said "If it's `vector::iterator`". My iterator is defined below as  `class vector <T> :: iterator`.

Comment: Templated or not, it doesn't matter. `iterator` is a class nested in `vector`. Nest it and walk away. Example: https://ideone.com/2LyVF3

Comment: In addition to what's already been said, It's hard to say without seeing the code where you use the iterators, but if you involve `const` you'll have problems. It's often easier to start making a `const_iterator` and build from there.

Comment: @user4581301 So you are implying I should move the entire iterator class inside of my vector class or just the forward declaration?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I havn't got that far. There is a script written by my professor that has a driver function to test the functionality of my vector. I am just trying to get my code to compile at this point.

Comment: Move the whole darn thing into `vector`. Function definitions can go out if you want but with a template there's usually little to be gained. Sidenote: `throw(const char *);` complicates things for little gain. [Here's Herb Sutter's piece on the Exception Specifier](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) They've been removed from the language as of the most recent Standard revision, C++17.

Comment: @user4581301 I am supposed to have the iterator class outside of the vector class as a part of my assignment.

Comment: An `iterator` is really not a special class, and was even taken out of the STL as a "mandatory" class to inherit from when making iterators. Just look up `iterator` and choose one simple (like `std::forward_iterator_tag`) and you'll find plenty of examples here on SO. Some are good, and some are mine. I tend to just make them work in a _range based for loop_. It's just a class to keep a state or similar.

Comment: Well, If it's gotta be outside the class, it's gotta be outside the class. Your first and most important job is to pass the class, so do something like this: https://ideone.com/iYGnO0

Comment: @user4581301 Clean and to the point!

Comment: @TedLyngmo LF's answer covers all the bases I was and brings up one case I hadn't considered. Give 'em an upvote if you'd be so good.

Comment: Will read it first ... didn't notice it until now. Yes, good stuff. The `end()` iterator could have gotten some special attention though.

Comment: Please make sure to post a [mcve] with an emphasis on minimal.   Remove everything from your posted code that is not absolutely required in order to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply move the definition of `iterator` into `vector`:

```
template <class T>
class vector {
public:
    class iterator {
        /* How you implement a iterator of type T */
    };

    iterator begin(); // for example

    // other fantastic stuff
};

template <class T>
vector<T>::iterator vector<T>::begin()
{
    // whatever
}
```

If you want to not define the `iterator` inside, this may do:

```
template <class T>
class vector {
public:
    class iterator; // only a declaration

    iterator begin(); // same

    // other fantastic stuff
};

template <class T>
class vector<T>::iterator {
    // the actual definition goes here
};

template <class T>
vector<T>::iterator vector<T>::begin()
{
    // same
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define `iterator` separately
and make `vector::iterator` an alias:

```
template <class T>
class iterator { /* real definition */ };

template <class T>
class vector {
public:
    using iterator = ::iterator<T>;
    // or typedef ::iterator<T> iterator;

    iterator begin(); // still the same

    // same fantastic stuff
};

template <class T>
vector<T>::iterator vector<T>::begin()
{
    // all the same
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was about to bundle my comments into an answer (because why the <expletive deleted> were they comments?) but it looks like you've just saved me the trouble. I'm going to proofread and then you've probably got an upvote.

Comment: Thank you. The upvote is <meaningless praise word deleted> good! xD